# Uploading png error with MultipartBody.Part and RequestBody in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am currently making a project for attendance application in Kotlin and I am trying to send a selfie image to the back-end for proof of attendance. I used MultipartBody.Part to send the image file and RequestBody to send the other stuff.

```
@Multipart
    @POST("shiftentry/clockin")
    suspend fun clockin(
        @Header("Authorization") auth: String,
        @Part("shift_entry_id") id: RequestBody,
        @Part("location") location:RequestBody,
        @Part file: MultipartBody.Part
    ): Response<Clocking>
```

So once I capture a selfie, the image will be saved to a file and that will be the file that is send to the server based on a button click.

```
button.setOnClickListener {

            val repository = Repository()
            val shiftingViewModelFactory = ShiftingViewModelFactory(repository)
            val fotoBody = photoSelfie.asRequestBody("image/png".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            val foto = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("selfie",photoSelfie.name,fotoBody)
            val id = entry.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            val loc = locationSpec.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())

            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, shiftingViewModelFactory).get(ShiftingViewModel::class.java)


            loginpref.fetchToken()?.let { viewModel.clockin(it, id, loc, foto) }

            viewModel.clocking.observe(this) { response ->
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val intent= Intent(this, VerificationActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }

        }
```

With no error on the code lines and requesting I thought it was fine, but there is an error in uploading the image. This is how the request looked like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=35f40f00-9e56-455d-86c5-9c7a1c754dd4
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 198195
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Authorization: fauna fnEEsNzngXACUQSP8HIOwApJi2P54RL8W-Ty3V9_FEf4Qvo67Nw
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --35f40f00-9e56-455d-86c5-9c7a1c754dd4
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="shift_entry_id"
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 18
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: 
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: 337807600467837519
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --35f40f00-9e56-455d-86c5-9c7a1c754dd4
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="location"
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 19
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: 
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: 37.4219983,-122.084
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --35f40f00-9e56-455d-86c5-9c7a1c754dd4
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="selfie"; filename="selfie.png4537237322485720665.png"
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: image/png
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Length: 197546
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: 
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: �����Exif����MM��*���������������������b�����������������������������2��������������v���������������i��������������������������������������sdk_gphone64_x86_64��2022:07:24 04:50:38��Google������������������W��������������_����������392������������392������������392���
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ������������g�    ���������������������������d�����������������o�����������������������������������������������������������������������������
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: ����������������������0220������������������d�����;��������������2022:07:24 04:50:38��2022:07:24 04:50:38������)������d��������������JFIF����������������C��
```

In the request, I get a very very lengthy unrecognizable stretch of characters(I only copied a fraction of it above). Although it does not causes a shutdown error, but I got a response error code 400 unexpected field. However, when I use RequestBody instead of multipartbody.part to send the image, I got error that file was not included in the request, so I assume the image somehow cannot be read by the server.

So, can anyone help in figuring out what part need to be fixed or is there another way to upload file other than with requestbody and multipartbody.part? and additional question What are those weird characters in the request?

I'm still very new in Kotlin and Android development, so any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Logs looks fine to me, it's the server that raises 400, so should check with them. One thing concerning is filename: `selfie.png4537237322485720665.png` - I guess it should work but it's a strange construct. Unrecognizable text is byte data of the image, so that's fine

Comment: Have a look at https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap, maybe it helps

Comment: @xinaiz so in the log everything is fine? Can you explain what are those characters then? are those like representation of the file or somethin? and yeah I took note of the filename, I was thinking of changing it, but I want to fix the uploading file first. Also, yes I did watch the link you send me when I was working on the code.

Comment: � characters are bytes that are not represented by ASCII characters (byte is 0-255 value, but ASCII characters are in range 0-127). So anything above 127 (or isn't visible character) is � or some other junk. What it is is basically pixel data of your image represented by PNG format along with some EXIF data (you can for example see `2022:07:24 04:50:38`, which is image metadata). It's very long because images take up to couple megabytes, which is millions of bytes, hence millions of characters in the log.